# android.process.acore has stopped working

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

I am having issues with my Lollipop (5.0.2) Android.

Basically every 1-2 seconds a message saying that "android.process.acore has stopped working" pops up and prevents me from using my phone normally.
This error started showing up when I tried to add a reddit account to "Reddit is fun" app but it also used to happen in the past after I added a new Google account (but then it disappeared magically).

This is the part of android log which describes the error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(13107): FATAL EXCEPTION: ContactsProviderWorker
E/AndroidRuntime(13107): Process: android.process.acore, PID: 13107
E/AndroidRuntime(13107): java.lang.RuntimeException: Package manager has died
E/AndroidRuntime(13107):    at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.queryContentProviders(ApplicationPackageManager.java:696)
E/AndroidRuntime(13107):    at com.android.providers.contacts.ContactDirectoryManager.getDirectoryProviderPackages(ContactDirectoryManager.java:224)
E/AndroidRuntime(13107):    at com.android.providers.contacts.ContactDirectoryManager.scanAllPackages(ContactDirectoryManager.java:261)
E/AndroidRuntime(13107):    at com.android.providers.contacts.ContactDirectoryManager.scanAllPackagesIfNeeded(ContactDirectoryManager.java:194)
E/AndroidRuntime(13107):    at com.android.providers.contacts.ContactDirectoryManager.scanAllPackages(ContactDirectoryManager.java:184)
E/AndroidRuntime(13107):    at com.android.providers.contacts.ContactsProvider2.updateDirectoriesInBackground(ContactsProvider2.java:1141)
E/AndroidRuntime(13107):    at com.android.providers.contacts.ContactsProvider2.performBackgroundTask(ContactsProvider2.java:933)
E/AndroidRuntime(13107):    at com.android.providers.contacts.ContactsProvider2ForLG.performBackgroundTask(ContactsProvider2ForLG.java:385)
E/AndroidRuntime(13107):    at com.android.providers.contacts.ContactsProvider2$1.handleMessage(ContactsProvider2.java:748)
E/AndroidRuntime(13107):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
E/AndroidRuntime(13107):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
E/AndroidRuntime(13107):    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
E/AndroidRuntime(13107): Caused by: android.os.TransactionTooLargeException
E/AndroidRuntime(13107):    at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(13107):    at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:496)
E/AndroidRuntime(13107):    at android.content.pm.IPackageManager$Stub$Proxy.queryContentProviders(IPackageManager.java:2816)
E/AndroidRuntime(13107):    at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.queryContentProviders(ApplicationPackageManager.java:694)
E/AndroidRuntime(13107):    ... 11 more
```

I tried to do everything suggested in other related questions, clearing contacts storage app cache, terminating it, disabling it, stopping Google contacts synchronization with cloud storage etc, but couldn't fix the problem.
I'd like to go to the root cause, if anybody else has ever experienced this issue and found a way to overcome this issue I'd like to know. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I found a workaround to this problem, basically this error comes up whenever there are too many requests per second (as to fill Android Runtime's internal buffer) which access phone data (for example contacts) from installed apps. I uninstalled many applications which I used rarely and the problem went away.

Answer (score 0):

There is no fixed solution to this problem but you can try these solutions which may work for you.

1. Clear Cache of Application which is getting this error.
2. Clear Cache and Data of Apps related to Contacts.
3. Update Android OS.
4. Reset App Preferences.
5. Uninstall recently installed apps.

   I found these solutions on website [itrickbuzz](http://www.itrickbuzz.com/unfortunately-the-process-android-process-acore-has-stopped/).Hope these solutions work for you

Comment: The link is broken